# keyDown() function not working in sikuliX IDE 1.1.0 using Python on Win 32-bit OS

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I want to switch on previous screen via below SikuliX **1.1.0** script but it is not working as needed and it seems that it skipping the below instruction:

---

```
KeyDown(Key.ALT)
type(Key.TAB)
keyUp()
```

---

Please guide if anybody have found solution on it **;)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to press ALT + TAB, you could use the next command:

```
type("\t", KeyModifier.ALT)
```

[Here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/274250) you will find a similar answer to your question. Works for other key modifiers too.

Comment: I am looking around to just press n hold ALT key then press TAB key once and then keyUp() to switch on previous application's screen.

Comment: As [this](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html) link show, you have to try like this:     type(Key.TAB, KeyModifier.SHIFT + Key.UP)

Comment: as per [RaiMan](https://dogfood.paddev.net/~raimund-hocke) comment in this [blog](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/238043) `keyDown` doesn't work in **SikuliX 1.1.0** , so please help me out to find codes in this function of `write`.

Comment: `write("#W5#S_#SPACE#S+#U%d#S-"%number_of_lines)`

_SHIFT, SPACE available in below code but for TAB how should I write? any guess?_

   `#W5 - after each real key wait 0.5 seconds
    #S_#SPACE - obvious ;-)
    #S+ - press and hold SHIFT key
    #U5 - 5 times UP key (after interpolation of number_of_lines by the 
    Python format feature %)
    #S- release SHIFT key`